# EntityFramework Linq Left Join Parsing Error - DotNet Core 1.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

I'm attempting to explicitly join 3 tables using a left outer join in a linq query and am running into linq parsing issues. Performing an inner join parses correctly and returns data but using the left outer fails.

Example:

```
 var query = from p in DatabaseContext.Products
                    where p.ClientID == clientID
                    join l in DatabaseContext.Licenses on p.ProductID equals l.ProductID into pl
                    from pli in pl.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join a in DatabaseContext.Articles on p.ArticleID equals a.ArticleID into pa
                    from pai in pa.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new SomeEntityDTO
                    {
                        SomethingFromP = p.Something,
                        SomethingFromL = pli.Something,
                        SomethingFromA = pai.Something
                    };
```

As both joined tables key off of the first table, I can test each individually by removing the other join, e.g., test the query for p to l and then for p to a.  These test queries function perfectly.  It's also possible to remove the left outer rule and receive a proper result.

```
var query = from p in DatabaseContext.Products
                    where p.ClientID == clientID
                    join l in DatabaseContext.Licenses on p.ProductID equals l.ProductID 
                    join a in DatabaseContext.Articles on p.ArticleID equals a.ArticleID 
                    select new SomeEntityDTO
                    ... the rest ...
```

Viewing the offending query in SQL Profiler (top code example) I see that the first two tables are successfully joined, e.g.:

```
SELECT p.Something, l.Something
FROM Products AS p
LEFT JOIN Licenses AS l ON p.ProductID = l.ProductID
WHERE p.ClientID = 5
ORDER BY p.ProductID
```

And, then right after this successful query, are another 2 queries (identical to each other):

```
SELECT a.ArticleID, a.Something, <all fields, even when not specified in query>
FROM Articles AS a
ORDER BY a.ArticleID
```

The outer joined 3 tables will successfully return an object, as long as I don't attempt to access a field from the "a" table.  When doing that, I recieve a Null Exception error, as that table was never really joined.

As stated, removing the outer join rule brings back a successfully joined query.

I have attempted to adjust the linq query figuring that the Linq parser had an issue, but to no avail:

```
var query = from p in DatabaseContext.Products
            from l in DatabaseContext.Licenses.Where(g => g.ProduktID == p.ProduktID).DefaultIfEmpty()
            from a in DatabaseContext.Articles.Where(g => g.ArticleID == p.ArticleID).DefaultIfEmpty()
            where ....
```

This parses to a set of CROSS APPLYs that doesn't function at all and the profiled query, when copied into a query editor window, doesn't run at all (as opposed to the 3 individual queries seen in the profiler for the first code example).  I have also attempted the more complicated lambdas, which also doesn't work.

Is this an error in the Linq parser?  Am I doing this completely wrong?  (According to the multiple answered questions here on explicit left outer joins (as opposed to natural associations), I'm doing it correctly.  But, it doesn't parse correctly.  I've avoided creating the associations so I can join them without explicitly defining the join.  Is that potentially required here and won't work properly without it?

Note:  Each table has complex keys but I only really need to join based on single key values (the DB is part of a product I can't change).

Using. DotNet Core, EntityFramework, EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, etc., all version 1.0.1.

Help?

Comment: It's not your fault. EF Core at this time still has issues with left outer joins (and queries in general).

Comment: @Ian Stoev Thanks for the answer. Is there another syntax I could use that has been proven to work?  At least until the way I'm attempting is fixed in a future release?

Comment: AFAIK, unfortunately no. Only `Include` works, you can search SO for similar issues. You may also try 1.1 beta, but looks like it's also unstable.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is to use EF6 instead of EFCore if you absolutely have to have complex Linq queries on your entites, even after the 1.1 release.  There are still too many things missing in EFCore compared to EF6.

Roadmap [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/07/29/entity-framework-core-1-1-plans/).

In my case, I kept EFCore and used the Context.Entity.FromSql(query) method in order to get the results.  This allowed me to utilize EFCore for most of the EF Entities, and thereby keeping a forward-looking approach to the application,  while allowing for special exceptions for complicated queries not based on an actual entity.  The plan is to replace those FromSql queries as EF Core matures.

Prior to deciding on .FromSql, I also tested a query on a View and on a stored procedure.  In both instances, I failed.  For stored procedures, named parameters is not yet implemented, and views are not currently supported unless you attempt to trick EF into thinking the view is actually a table (which brings its own issues).

In order to access EF Core .FromSql, you need to install the following package:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational

Comment: Can you please explain about this "you attempt to trick EF into thinking the view is actually a table" I saw info about this "trick" twice (this comment for example https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/245#issuecomment-219787628), but nobody say how they do it.

Comment: @PilgrimViis I simply define it just like I would define a table in the entity model, with a Table("MyView") annotation and ensure the view has a [Key] as well (simply a computated one such as "DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ...)".

Comment: for info i have just started with dotnet core and using framework core 1.0.1 it was failing. However i noticed an update (1.1.0), installed that and now a doing a 'left' join the old entity way seams to be working